# while typing in edittext box how can i find a data from sqlite database?

Tags: android

I am making app for finding number plates of india. my database contains two columnns "code" and "city" code contains data like MH1,MH2 etc. and city contains data like Pune,Mumbai.

App contains one edittext box and listview.

Listview consists whole data from database like GJ3 Rajkot, GJ10 Jamnagar etc.

If I write GJ in edittext box whole only data of GJ must be appear in the listview.

I got this query from one person but how can i integrate with edittext box

```
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(
        "select * from table_name where column_name = ?",
        new String[] { "search" });
```

Comment: Its like AutoCompleteTextView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: How you are adding data in ListView. You pass data in list or array or any other.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `AutoCompleteTextView` instead of normal `EditText`.

I think you'll find this useful : http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

Please see following link: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: You can also see: http://hello-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/using-autocompletetextview-with-sqlite.html

Comment: This is also useful: http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-autocompletetextview-sqlite-and-dependent-fields/

Comment: If i use only AutoCompeleteTextView then it will fetch only static data i want to fetch it from dataabase how can i do this ?

Comment: You can get the example from following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912399/using-cursorloader-to-query-sqlite-db-and-populate-autocompletetextview

Comment: i am enable to search a data from database for example if i write AR in edittext it display all records of AR but it display only in Log cat...Whenever i type anything in Edittext box Listview is diappeared..now i want to display the same data which displays in logcat